# Web page not responsive: how to use position absolute and relative?

Tags: html, css, css-position

**I made a simple website however the divs are not appearing properly**

- I have a div  `section-one` that is `position: relative` *[green]* and I a second div called `silver-break-bar` div that is `position: absolute` inside.

I also have a `section-two` div [red color] below `section-one`. **The issue is three fold.**

1. The  `section-two` is displaying over the green div. Why Doesn't is display below the green div? I've even made `body {height: auto}`

[image: ![enter image description here]

2. The second issue is I've made my `red-car img`  `padding:0 margin:0` so i doesn't go outside of page, however the div is **still not wrapping around image?**
3. The third issue is when I resize the browser the pink div is covering up the headline? Why is that?

[image]

Update: Finally, I am trying to create divs that display underneath each other i.e section-one, section-two, section-three similar to this. 
[image]

UPDATE: Here is the code, sorry I forget to add it!

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Responsive Navigation Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var pull        = $('#pull');
                menu        = $('nav ul');
                menuHeight  = menu.height();

            $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                menu.slideToggle();
            });

            $(window).resize(function(){
                var w = $(window).width();
                if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                    menu.removeAttr('style');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='main-header'>
    <nav class="clearfix">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How ItS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Why Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
    </nav>
</div>

    <div id='section-one'>
            <h1> Order anything from anywhere in Karachi instantly at your doorstep. </h1>
                <div class='silver-line-break'></div>
                <div id='fee-estimate-box'>
                    <form id='fee-estimate-form' action="#">
                            <legend>Delivery Fee Calculator</legend>
                            <span>First name: </span> <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
                            <span>Last name: </span> <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </div>                  <div class='silver-break-bar'>
                    <img id='red-car' src="img/red-car.png" alt="" height="60%" width="30%;">
                </div>
    </div>

    <div id='section-two'>
        <p>section two div</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Basic Styles */
* {
   margin-top:  0px;
   padding: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
  height: auto;
    background-color: #ece8e5;
}

/***** NAVIGATION ***/
/* Clearfix */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #283744;

}
nav ul {
    padding-right: :5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 40px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0%;
}
nav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
nav a {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;*/
}
nav li a {
    /*border-right: 1px solid #576979;*/
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    background-color: #8c99a4;
}
nav a#pull {
    display: none;
}

/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav {
        height: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: auto;
      float: none;
    }
    nav li {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
        border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    }
    nav a {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        text-indent: 25px;
    }
}

/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    nav {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
        display: none;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav a#pull {
        display: block;
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav a#pull:after {
        content:"";
        background: url('../img/nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        top: 10px;
    }
}

/*Smartphone*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

  nav ul {
    float: none;
  }

    nav li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    }
}

#section-one {
    position: absolute;;
    background-color:  #80be05;
    margin-top: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
  height: 85%;

}

#section-one h1 {
  position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2%;
    font-family: 'TeX Gyre Adventor', 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 57px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px;
}

#section-one .silver-line-break {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: silver;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#section-two {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
#section-one #red-car {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 75%;
  top: 60%;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#section-one #fee-estimate-box {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;;
  width: 70%;
  height: 40%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 2%;
}
```

Comment: share your css and html pls ( only the relevant parts )

Comment: You haven't provided a [MCVE], but it looks like the answer to all three of your questions is "Because you used absolute positioning". It isn't an appropriate tool to create the layout you gave in the last image.

Comment: Given the problems you are encountering, you should check out bootstrap. It's pretty damn easy to build responsive pages with it.

Comment: SORRY! I pressed the publish button accidentally. The source code is added!

Comment: @Borjante I realise bootstrap is simple to use. I am avoiding bootstrap because it makes this too easy, I'd like to be able to make things raw without the use of bootstrap

Comment: Bootstrap might be worth utilising to understand how responsive works though, then build your own CSS based off of what you've learnt from it

Comment: Exactly, jump to the bootstrap source code, take a look at the .row class, the different types of columns classes. Maybe the .container class as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well. i don't know where to start :) so many issues here

made a **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5hw19nw/3/)**

1. IF you want sections to go one after another and not over each other , DO NOT USE `position:absolute` EVER !
2. you wrote somewhere `margin-top:0 auto` , that is not correct, margin-top has only one value , `margin:0 auto` is correct and means  `margin-top:0,margin-right:auto,margin-bottom:0,margin-left:auto`
3. `.section-two` ( the red line ), if you want it to be right after the navigation, why don't you put it after the nav in the html ?. if you don't want to use that, then yes....use position:absolute on that div. BUT i suggest you make your html easier to work with

let me know if it works

code :

```
#section-one {
    background-color:  #80be05;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    width:100%
   }

#section-one h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2%;
    font-family: 'TeX Gyre Adventor', 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 57px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px;
}

#section-one .silver-line-break {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    float:left;
    background-color: silver;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

#section-two {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float:left;
  background-color: red;
  padding:10px 0 5px;
}
#section-one #red-car {
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  background-color: blue;
  width:25%;
  height:100px;
}

#section-one #fee-estimate-box {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  float:left;
  margin-left:2.5%;
  margin-right:2.5%;


}
```

read more about CSS position here : [CSS POSITION](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Hey! So this is what I am getting. So the red div is working fine. I want it to be below green so thats good. However the form and the img is behind green div  i think here is the link http://imgur.com/8F5QK3h

Comment: Also the silver break bar is also disappeared

Comment: so you want the red to be after the green and not after the navigation ? and the pink and blue to be inside the green area ?

Comment: Thanks! So what exactly was the reason why the blue and pink were behind?

Comment: Also you said: "IF you want sections to go one after another and not over each other , DO NOT USE position:absolute EVER !" -- So does that mean I should be using position:relative?

Comment: well. do not use any position . but instead build your html so that your sections stay one after another. not on top of eachother.    `position:absolute` you give to an element that you want to stay on top of another element with `position:relative`

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to mobile view of your website, it's always better not to use position `absolute` in your main divs like header or footer as it positions them in respect of their parent. If you really want to position some div using `absolute`, you should remember to set its parent to div to `position: relative`, so that you can position it 'inside' the parent div and it won't go outside it, unless you give it negative `left`, `right` etc. But keep in mind that using `position: relative` is far better, all your divs will position relatively to each other, and you're less likely to encounter problems. Hope that helps.